# How to generate dynamic empty 2D array without default constructor in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

I have a class named `Test` and I'd like to create empty 2D array that will hold instances of that class and than add them later one by one using constructor that accepts parameters.

Basically, I'd just like to reserve memory that I will fill in later with objects. It needs to bee on a `heap` since I will have class that will generate 2D arrays of different sizes.

This was my first approach but it doesn't really work since `Test` class doesn't have default constructor:

```
Test** arr;
arr = new Test*[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    arr[i] = new Test[10];
```

**[EDIT]**

Here is my full test code. All in all, I'm getting wrong values out, it should be numbers from 0 to 99:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test {
private:
    short number;
public:
    Test(short n) {
        this->number = n;
    }
    short getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
};

int main() {
    Test** arr;
    arr = new Test*[10*10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        arr[i] = new Test(i);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            cout << arr[i][j].getNumber() << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any advantage of this above vectors really. Is there a reason you do this instead of using a vector of vectors of `Test` (except the non-default-constructor issue which you still have)?

Comment: More regarding your current troubles, have you thought about using pointers? I.e. a matrix of pointers instead of values.

Comment: I'm kind of exploring possibilities here, I'm primarily interested in reserving memory for a 2D matrix in a simple manner.

Comment: Yes, but I get problems with that as well.

Comment: If you want to create a raw 2D array of a class that doesn't have a default constructor, and add the objects later, you'd have to make it a 2D array of pointers. You can't "add" anything to a 2D array of objects, the objects are in the array already.

Comment: I actually have made that but I'm having some weird memory issues.

Comment: If you're having "problems" and "some weird memory issues" you should probably ask about them, instead of asking how to create a 2D array which  you seem to know already?

Comment: I don't really, I'm doing a guess work @zenith

Comment: I have updated my post with full code so if anyone can take a look at it that would be great.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it... I just need more pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using a default constructor with default parameters?

```
Test(int i = 0) {. . .}
```